# Name filter for eclipse.ui.menus

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, menu, contextmenu

I've got a menu contribution, realised through `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point. I'd like to offer this menu contribution only for specific file extensions (e.g. *.pld), but I couldn't figure out how to do this with "visibleWhen". Any ideas?

---------------Update----------------
My extension point so far:

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?before=additions">
         <command
               commandId="org.variability.configurator.commands.createPlc"
               icon="icons/PlcWizard.png"
               label="Create Product"
               style="push">
            <visibleWhen
                  checkEnabled="false">

            </visibleWhen>
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

Cheers, 
Phil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of property tests you can use:

```xml
<test
   property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
   value="*.pld">
</test>
```

and

```xml
<test
   property="org.eclipse.core.resources.extension"
   value="pld">
</test>
```

You will need to iterate over the selection so the full visible when would be something like:

```xml
<visibleWhen
      checkEnabled="false">
    <iterate
         ifEmpty="false"
         operator="or">
        <test
            property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
            value="*.pld">
        </test>
    </iterate>
</visibleWhen>
```

Comment: Thx, but both didn't worked. Am I right with this way:

....
<visibleWhen
      checkEnabled="false">
          <test
                property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
     value="*.pld">
        </test>
</visibleWhen>
...

Comment: Expanded answer with full visibleWhen