# Name filter for org.eclipse.ui.menus - also for editor view

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, menu, contextmenu

I've got a menu defined by this extension point: `org.eclipse.ui.menus`.
Its location URI is`popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any`, meaning that it's showed also from the different explorer views and from the editor view (right click somewhere on the code).

I want this menu to show up only for some extension. I used greg's answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776876/name-filter-for-eclipse-ui-menus) and it works very good for explorer views.
How can I do the same filter **also** for the editor view?

I want to change it in a way that if someone right-clicks from the editor view (and from explorer views) on a file it will show up only if it's a "*.myextension" file.

Thanks.

**Trying to combine filters** - following greg's answer, here's my code that doesn't work as expected.

```
        <visibleWhen
              checkEnabled="false">
            <iterate
                 ifEmpty="false"
                 operator="or">
                <or>
                <test
                    property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
                    value="*.myextension">
                </test>
                </or>
                <or>
                  <with variable="activeEditorInput">
                     <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                        <test
                            property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
                            value="*.myextension">
                        </test>
                     </adapt>
                  </with>   
               </or>                
            </iterate>
        </visibleWhen>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an editor you can test the 'active editor input' using something like:

```xml
<visibleWhen
  checkEnabled="false">
  <with variable="activeEditorInput">
     <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
        <test
            property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
            value="*.myextension">
        </test>
     </adapt>
  </with>
</visibleWhen>
```

This is taking the active editor input, getting the `IResource` that is being edited and testing that.

Combining might give:

```xml
<visibleWhen
   checkEnabled="false">
   <or>
     <with variable="activeEditorInput">
       <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
          <test
              property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
              value="*.myextension">
          </test>
       </adapt>
     </with>
     <iterate
           ifEmpty="false"
           operator="or">
        <test
            property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name"
            value="*.myextension">
        </test>
     </iterate>
   </or>
 </visibleWhen>
```

Comment: greg thank you for the quick answer. How can I combine these two filters (for "activeEditorInput" and from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776876/name-filter-for-eclipse-ui-menus?noredirect=1&lq=1 ) ?

Comment: You can use `<or>...</or>` to combine tests.

Comment: I still can't manage to make it work. Can you please take a look at my original question? I updated it with my code.

Comment: One <or> with the alternates in that single <or>.  Added example

Comment: It works almost like I wanted, but there's one problem: if I open a myextension file and then go to "Project Explorer" for example and right a non-myextension file, the menu is showed up. Every other case works perfectly. Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Because the test is only for the active editor input which works even when the editor is not the active part. You would have to add additional tests on the active part - I'm not sure there is a good test that will do that.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for your help.